# Django "Reverse for 'question_update' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found."error

Tags: django

NoReverseMatch at /answer_update/1/16
Reverse for 'question_update' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['question\/(?P[0-9]+)\/update\/$']

I am trying to make a comment update function. But it doesn't work. 
Someone please help me out.

urls.py

```
path('answer_update/<int:qpk>/<int:apk>',views.answer_update, name='answer_update'),
```

views.py

```
def answer_update(request, qpk, apk):
answer = get_object_or_404(Answer, pk=apk)
question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=qpk)

if request.method == "POST":
    form = AnswerForm(request.POST, instance=answer)
    if form.is_vaild():
        form.save()
        return redirect('detail_question', pk=apk)
else:
    form = AnswerForm(instance = answer)
return render(request, 'detail_question.html',{'form':form})
```

detail_question.html

```
<div>
<h1>Answer_list</h1>
<div>
    {% for answer in answers %}
        <div>
            {% if answer.image %}
                <img src="{{ answer.image.url}}" height=200>
            {% endif %}
            <p> {{ answer.content }} </p>
            <p> {{ answer.author }} </p>
            {% if user == answer.author %}
                <a href="{% url 'answer_update' question.pk answer.pk %}">update</a>
            {% endif %}
            {% if user == answer.author %}
                <a href="{% url 'answer_remove' question.pk answer.pk %}">delete</a>
            {% endif %}

            {% if user == question.author and question.selected == False %}
                <a href="{% url 'select_question' question.pk answer.pk %}">select</a>
            {% endif %}
            <hr>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: That's not coming from anything in this code. Please post the full traceback and the place where you generate the URL for question_update.

Answer (score 0):

> return render(request, 'detail_question.html',{'form':form})

You do not pass "answers" variable to 'detail_question.html' template

Only context you pass is {'form':form}

It seems to be form view, but template is for list view...